# onclick action not happening on iphones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iphone

I have an image that displays a dropdown menu on click. This is the HTML code:

```
   <div class="menu">
     <img  id="menu_img" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dqn5eqmwt/image/upload/v1493014197/Menu_jwzusk.svg">
     <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <a id="Edprof">Edit Profile</a>
        <a id="Deprof">Delete Profile</a>
        <a id="Chistory">Check History</a>
        <a id="Bevents">Book Events</a>
        <a id="Getout">Logout</a>
     </div>
  </div>
```

This is the CSS for the entire menu:

```
.menu {
display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    height:55px; /* 150/640 */
    width:55px;/*150/1536*/
    top: 2.5%;
    right: 10.0208333333%;
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
 }
#menu_img{
    width:55px;
    height:55px;
    cursor: pointer;
 }

/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
.menu:hover, .menu:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #7de88a;
    border: 6px solid #7de88a;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 300%;
    right: 0px;
    left: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
 }

/* Links inside the dropdown */
 .dropdown-content a {
    color: #c43396;
    background-color: #fff3bb;
    font-family: Chewy;
    border: 6px solid #7de88a;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 2.5px;
    margin-bottom: 2.5px;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    display: block;
  }
```

Finally, this is the JS for the onclick of image event:

```
$(function(){ 
   $('#menu_img').on('click touch',function() {
   document.getElementById("myDropdown").style="display:block";
 })
});
```

I also have a JS to hide the dropdown on click anwhere in the window other than the menu_img. This works perfectly well on laptops and android phones. The only problem is iPhones. On click, the background color changes, which is actually the hover action. But dropdown menu does not appear.

From what I read these are the checks I've already tried: 
1. Added cursor:pointer to menu_img in CSS
2. Removed hover action and tested if click would happen then
3. added onclick() function to the HTML code
4. Added touch along with click as the event trigger in the JS code
5. Checked if it displays on double click(but that just zooms the page)

None of these have worked for me. Any suggestions/tests/help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why not use `$("#myDropdown").show()`?

Comment: If you take `display: none;` out of the CSS, can you see the dropdown when you load the page?

Comment: Add `alert("clicked");` to the function to see if it's running.

Comment: jQuery is smarter than most of us, it knows all the right CSS settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited your code and run it on my server. It works perfectly on all devices. A personal tip: use jQuery everywhere or don't use it at all.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#menu_img').click(function(){
     $('#myDropdown').show();
   });
});
```

Comment: Personal tip: use `.hide()` and `.show()` instead of setting CSS.

Comment: Bah, @DanPhilip posted the same answer before me :c Sorry for posting the same thing.